# integral subschems of geometrically integeral schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a geometrically integral surface over a field $k$ and let $C$ be an integral curve on $X$. I want to know whether $C$ is geometrically irreducible over $k$ or not.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  There are examples where $C$ is not a geometrically irreducible curve.  Consider the case where$X$ equals $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ with a coordinate projection to $\mathbb{A}^1_k$.  By the Primitive Element Theorem, every finite, separable extension field $L/k$ is realized as an irreducible divisor in $\mathbb{A}^1_k$. The inverse image of that irreducible divisor under the coordinate projection is an integral curve in $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ that is not geometrically irreducible.

Comment: More explicitly: $x^2 + y^2 = 0$ is integral but not geometrically irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks @ Lughran and @starr. I want to know can we put some condition on the surface or the ground field(not algebraically closed) so that all integral curves are geometrically irreducible over the ground field?

Comment: Separably closed would suffice, i guess, because totally inseparable extensions can make integral curves non-reduced but not reducible.

Comment: Yes separable closure of the ground field is enoughThanks@ Will Sawin.